# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 on Reference issues

Tags: c++, xcode7

I have an error running in my Mac x64 when i notice the code was successful run in x86 windows machine (Library code download from Github). But i think this wasn't the issues of c++ code coz it seem well define. I had search most of the solutions had given but non of the way it can solve my issues so far.

Error :

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "libedm::CRandSequence::Poll()", referenced from:
          libedm::CDataset::SubSet(int, libedm::CDataset&) const in DataSet.o
```

DataSet.cpp

```
#include "RandSequence.h"
using namespace libedm;

...
bool CDataset::SubSet(int DataNum, CDataset &TrainSet) const
{
    //sub set of a data set
    int FinalSize=DataNum;
    if(DataNum>CaseInfo.Height)
        FinalSize=CaseInfo.Height;

    TrainSet.Matrix.clear();
    CRandSequence RandSequence(FinalSize);
    for(int i=0;i<FinalSize;i++)
    {
        int TrainNum=RandSequence.Poll();
        TrainSet.Matrix.push_back(Matrix[TrainNum]);
    }

    TrainSet.CaseInfo=CaseInfo;
    TrainSet.CaseInfo.Height=FinalSize;
    TrainSet.CreatingTime=0;
    return true;
}
```

RandSequence.cpp

```
int CRandSequence::Poll()
{
    int Left=(int)OldIds.size();
    if(Left==0)
        return -1;

    //select
    int Selected=IntRand(Left);
    int Ret=OldIds[Selected];
    OldIds.erase(OldIds.begin()+Selected);

    return Ret;
}
```

RandSequence.h

```
namespace libedm
{
    class CRandSequence
    {
    public:
        int Poll();
        CRandSequence(int UMax);
        void Reset();

    private:
        vector<int> OldIds;
        int Max;
    };
}
```

I had also try did my setting at `my project->Build Setting` as suggested from some others expert here.

```
1) Apple LLVM Language C++ > C++ Standard Library = libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)
2) Architectures > Architectures = 32-bit Intel (i386)- $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
3) Development > OS X Development Target = OS X 10.11 (tried to reduce)
4) Search Paths > Header Search Paths = (All i had header was linked..)
```

Comment: The code you posted is not complete, i.e. not the exact code giving that error message. How do I know? Well, it complains about stuff in the `libedm` namespace. I see no such namespace in your code. Your *actual* code might have problems that the code you posted does not. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes Dev, was my mistake, i had just updated the code.

Comment: 1) Not minimal. There's lots of member variables, functions etc. that have nothing to do with your actual problem. 2) Not complete. I cannot copy & paste & compile to see the same problem you are seeing. (This would need *all* the *minimal* code, and because we're looking at a linker error, information on what you are compiling and linking in which sequence. Like a Makefile...) And thus, 3) Not verifyable. As a bug tracker entry, this would be closed as "cannot reproduce".

Comment: Thanks Dev, sorry for all inconvenient cause. Im appreciated for your comment and i will post it in better way next time. Since this entire code related with 37K lines of code, is hard for me the summaries a better way for your simulation. However, my problem was solved perfectly now. Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Ref. [Machete Debugging](http://rootdirectory.de/wiki/MacheteDebugging).

Comment: @D_9268, since the problem is fixed, please post the answer and mark it as correct (to inform other people that they should spend any time on reading of the question).